# Overflow-X , not working at all?

Tags: css

I'm doing this proyect: http://jimenarguelles.mx. There is an odd situation with the overflow.

Please scroll the website in horizontal, that should not happen at all.

the `class="sidebar"` is `position:absolute` `right:0`

what do you think? Do I need to re-structure my css or html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this onto 'body':

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```